# Validate mobile number into 10 digit numbers in php jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to validate phone number jquery when alphabets are pressed it as to display error message. Below code takes enters digits but doesnt validate to 10 digits. How to validate to 10 digit number.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function() {
   $("#phno").bind("keypress", function (event) {
                if (event.charCode != 0) {
                       var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{10}$");
                    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
                    if (!regex.test(key)) {
                      alert("Please enter valid Student Phone No");
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
 });
```

Comment: wrong pattern try this: `^[0-9]{10}$`

Comment: just use a validate plugin but if you insist just take the value in a variable and check if (var.length == 10){proceed}else{alert('error')}

Comment: Some people use space or dash in their phone numbers. Maybe allow them but then delete them before you regex the phonenumber?

Comment: I used     var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{10}$"); it doesnt allow numbers and alphabets too

Comment: the problem is the key is contained only currently pressed . so it will always less than 10 digit only . so use val() to get the value .

Comment: what about using a HTML5 `<input type="tel" pattern="a regex here">` that will be helpful when using smartphones too ? does it have to take care of the format (nat ? int'l ? +33 ?) ?

Comment: did you solve the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var regex = new RegExp("/^[0-9]{1,10}$/");
```

Or try this

```
var str='0123456789';
console.log(str.match(/^\d{10}$/)); // retunr null if don't match
```

Comment: It is not allwoing numbers and alphabets too.

Comment: try this again  /^[a-z0-9]+$/i

Comment: No it  is not taking numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for you which EXACTLY checks for 10 digits, only accepts numbers and nothing else:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#phno").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a.match(/^\d{9}$/)) {
      console.log("Perfect!");
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid. Ensure, there are 10 digits.");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='phno' />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```js
$(function() {
   $("#phno").bind("keydown", function (e) {
        if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
             // 0-9
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (!val.match(/^\d{9}$/))
            {
               console.log("it is a number but nut match 10 digit")
            }
            else
            {
               console.log("success");
               return false; // to restrict user to not enter more than 10 digit
            }
        }
        else
        {
           if(e.keyCode == 8)
              return true; // backspace
           alert("Please enter valid Student Phone No");
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
        }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='phno' />
```

Comment: I need to validate it to 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

Just use this jquery function and restrict only ten digits in your html code as

```
<input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="10" id="phone"/>
```

and use this below jquery function

```
$("#phone").bind("keypress", function (event) {  
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
    var phone_val=$('#phone').val();
    if((phoneno.test(phone_val)))
    {
     return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {    
     return false;  
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this...

```
var num = '1234567890';
if(!isNaN(num) && num.length ==10){ alert('Validated');  }
else { alert('Not a 10 digit number'); }
```